# Division of Normal and Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I am trying to understand the following: If $X$ is normally distributed and $Y$ is distributed according to the Poisson distribution, how to find out which distribution $Z=X/Y^2$ has?

Is there any general technique to answer such questions?

Comment: Quite generally, if $X$ has PDF $f$ and $Z$ is independent of $X$ and integer valued, nonzero, with PMF $(p_n)$, then $T=X/Z$ has PDF $g$ with $$g(t)=\sum_n|n|\,p_n\,f(nt).$$

Comment: The title says "normal and poisson distribution" while the post says "normal and gamma." Which is it?

Comment: Further, you need to specify whether you are referring to a standard Normal or general Normal.

Comment: I have removed my Comment and deleted my Answer because the edited question is no longer the one I dealt with earlier. I believe that @Did's comment is also irrelevant now. Once you settle whether you are necessarily using standard normal, you can try the standard method for such problems. Do a bivariate transformation $W = X,$ and $Z = X/Y^2.$ Note the region of support of $(W, Z).$ Find the Jacobian and the joint density function of $(W,Z)$. "Integrate out" $W$ to find the desired marginal of $Z$.

Comment: @ASuit Just. Don't. Do. That.